# Why IE browser show "scanstyles does nothing in webkit/firefox internet explorer"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer, browser

In IE browser show some time this script error `scanstyles does nothing in webkit/firefox/opera`.
Can we fix this issue on our code?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_8/scanstyles-does-nothing-in-webkit-mozilla/77533b99-7b3d-4a5b-b620-2cdb777f45c7?msgId=6a12f2ce-d1d9-42f0-b661-10863e937fa2

Comment: Tried Google? http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/158256-Scanstyles-does-nothing-in-Webkit-Firefox

Comment: Thank you guys. but i want to fix it on my code. any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code you are using that triggers this error.

Comment: (As you discovered on your now-deleted question, brief questions with no/limited detail tend to earn downvotes. I think you might just have been lucky on your other questions, which are - in my opinion - also too brief).

Comment: @halfer thank u... actually i ask anybody already faced his problem and how there were fixed it in code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Locate curvycorners.js and comment out 
curvycorners.alert("Scanstyles does nothing in ...");

See http://www.witti.ws/blog/2013/12/09/scanstyles-does-nothing-webkitfirefox for a more complete explanation.